# Reordering one matrix's rows based on another matrix's columns

Tags: r, matrix

I have a Matrix A and Matrix B. Matrix A has dimensions of 155 x 852963, while Matrix B has dimensions of 25833 x 132. Matrix A's rows has all of the names of Matrix B's columns, but not the other way around.

The new matrix, Matrix C, should only the names of Matrix A which are in Matrix B, and be ordered in the same way that Matrix B's column are. Matrix C's dimensions would be 132 x 852963.

Matrix A looks like :
[image: Matrix A]

Matrix B looks like:
[image]

So Matrix C should look like this:

```
       rs1571149 | rs1571150 | rs7290
AC1
-----
AC10
-----
AC100
```

So basically, just to clarify...for the new Matrix C, I want to keep all of the columns of Matrix A in tact, only include names that are in Matrix B and just be reordered so that the rows match Matrix B's columns order.

Thanks in advance for any help! :)

Comment: How about `matC <- matA[colnames(matB),]`, or perhaps `matC <- matA[colnames(matB)[-1],]` if you don't want the `ProbeID` included

Comment: Or maybe `matC <- matA[rownames(matA) %in% colnames(matB), ]`.

Comment: Oh nice, so when i use `matC <- matA[colnames(matB), ]` why does it output an error `Error in .local(x, i, j, ..., drop) : No match for one or more row selections` and also I tried `matC <- matA[colnames(matB)[-1],]` and it works but it only gives 131 rows instead of 132, why is that?